Fixing garage door problem
The Lift Master control on the wall does not work, only has a message “press bar to activate control. See user manual”.
When I use the remote I only get a clicking sound and the light flicks on and off.

This is often the sensor (down low) being obstructed or kicked out of alignment. Check that and let us know.

is it battery or power operated

What did the user manual say?

press and hold.
